# How can I select the amount of individual visitors in PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I've made a simple script that adds a new row in a table 'visits' for every visit.
Now I want to know how I can select the amount of **individual** visitors.
Using `SELECT COUNT(*), IP FROM visits GROUP BY IP` will return all individual visitors, but how would I return the amount of rows in that result? I tried something like COUNT(COUNT(*)), but that obviously doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting the distinct count of IP addresses across the entire table:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP) FROM visits;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DISTINCT` function:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`IP`)) FROM `visits`
```

Comment: @MartijnNoordermeer Oops... `:(`

Comment: @MartijnNoordermeer Sorry, it works without `GROUP BY \`IP\``: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c3877/5